# Dropdown menu in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python Gui Tkinter. I was making an application in which one window has a drop down menu. The code is below, but it is not executing. It just opens a window but no menu. What is the issue with the code? I have tried multiple times. Can anybody suggest how should I proceed?

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title("Data Entry Window") 
menu = Menu(root) 
root.config(menu = menu)  

subMenu = Menu(menu) 
menu.add_cascade(label = "Entry", menu = subMenu)  
subMenu.add_command(label = "New Entry") 
subMenu.add_separator() 
subMenu.add_command(label = "Update Entry") 
subMenu.add_separator() 
subMenu.add_command(label = "Delete Entry")  

editMenu = Menu(menu) 
menu.add_cascade(label = "Report", menu = editMenu)  
editMenu.add_command(label = "Day Report") 
editMenu.add_separator() 
editMenu.add_command(label = "Range Report")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code as posted works for me when I put it in a file and run 'python test.py`. Looks like you did everything ok to me (aside from not adding 'tearoff=False' :) )

Comment: save it in file and run in console/terminal/cmd/powershell  and maybe you see some error message. If you run in IDLE then problem can be IDLE which also use Tkinter and mainloop() to display windows and there can be a conflict.

Answer (score -2):

You write

```
from Tkinter import *
```

This is wrong. The problem will solved if you write it like this:

```
from tkinter import *
```